# Disable /api/entities route to get the list

Tags: api-platform.com

When creating an entity with `@ApiResource`, you get 5 routes:

```
GET    /api/entities
POST   /api/entities
GET    /api/entities/{id}
DELETE /api/entities/{id}
PUT    /api/entities/{id}
```

How can I disable the first route ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should customize the `collectionOperations` attribute in your `@ApiResource` annotation

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={}
 * )
 */
```

For more information: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#enabling-and-disabling-operations